# How to display the total count in a page and overall total count for a column in splunk dashboard

Tags: sorting, dashboard, splunk

I am using `addcoltotals` to count the overall total of a count column. But the result is displayed in the last page (if I have more than 1 page). I want to display both the no of counts in that page as well as overall total count in all pages.
Lets say I have total 100 records
And in first page it's 50 ,second it's 20 and in third it's 30.
Then in first page it should show 50 out of 100 and in second 20out of 100 like that

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [`sort`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sort) your data to put the totals row on top (though, of course, it might move if you sort by clicking afterwards):

```
<search>
| addcoltotals
| sort 0 - someFieldThatHasBeenTotaled
```

---

Always use `| sort 0` so that if you have more than 10k rows, Splunk doesn't truncate the resultset at 10k rows